# How can I validate uniqueness of another association key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, associations

I have a `ClothRecord` model. And this model belongs to `OrderItem` model. And belongs to `Cloth` model, too. And this `Cloth` model has `kind` column.

In this situation, new `ClothRecord` record is created. This record have one cloth that kind column is 'shell'.  And another `ClothRecord` is created. This record have cloth too. But this record should NOT HAVE SAME `kind` column. But if this record belongs to another OrderItem, then it's OK. So I think below code works, but didn't.

```
class ClothRecord < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cloth
  belongs_to :order_item

  validates_uniqueness_of :cloth_kind, scope: :order_item_id

  def cloth_kind
     cloth.kind
  end
end
```

Do I should code custom validation method? If I should how code this complicated validation?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is weird, but you can probably use *custom validation method* to do something like this (untested)

```
class ClothRecord < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cloth
  belongs_to :order_item

  validate :record_uniqueness

  def cloth_kind
     cloth.kind
  end

  def record_uniqueness
    similar = ClothRecord.joins(:cloth)
      .exists?('clothes.kind = ? AND order_items.id = ?', cloth_kind, order_item)

    errors.add(:cloth, "must be unique to order item") if similar
    # You can add the error to :order_item_id too
  end
end
```

I think it is easier if you can just ensure uniqueness of `ClothRecord` + `Cloth` + `OrderItem`, as such

```
validates_uniqueness_of :cloth, scope: :order_item_id
```

You can also check `:conditions` parameter for `validates_uniqueness_of`, where you can specify additional query fragment to `where`.